# Multiple values returned when setting a path for days in the calendar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

```
<tr><td width="16" align="center" class="calWeekend"><a class="cal" href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(19);">19</a></td><td width="16" align="center" class="cal"><a class="cal" href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(20);">20</a></td><td width="16" align="center" class="cal"><a class="cal" href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(21);">21</a></td><td width="16" align="center" class="cal"><a class="cal" href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(22);">22</a></td><td width="16" align="center" class="cal"><a class="cal" href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(23);">23</a></td><td width="16" align="center" class="cal"><a class="cal" href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(24);">24</a></td><td width="16" align="center" class="calWeekend"><a class="cal" href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(25);">25</a></td></tr>
```

My calendar looks like that for days(that's part of it for the days section)

thw issue i'm facing with it is, let's say i want to select the 5th day:

```
//a[@href=contains(text(),'5')]
```

i get 5, 15 and 25.
i can specify the first element but it's a very bad practice
How can i precise the exact value for the number ?

Comment: What about using the full href dinamically instead. Looks the same for every day. href="javascript: g_Calendar.clickDay(YourDay);"

Comment: can you please add a full solution answer for that as xpath

Answer (score 1):

if there is no other element contain same text then you can use

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('5')
```

or you can use xpath also

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='5']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see inner text is also available. Why don't you try to read the exact value by using

```
//a[text()='5']   //which will return only one day
```